# Can we construct $f_{XY}(x,y)$ if $f_X(x)$ is known and the relationship of $Y$ on $X$ is known?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$,
If $Y=g(X)$,
i.e $Y$ is a function of $X$

then,can we construct the joint probability density function of $X $ and $Y$ ,
i.e, $f_{XY}(x,y)$
 if probability density function of $X$ , i.e, $f_X(x)$ is known ?

**For example**:
If $X$ is normally distributed with mean $=0$ and standard deviation $=1$,
i.e,
$$ f_X(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} $$
and, $Y=X^2$ ;
Then can we find $f_{XY}(x,y)$?

Comment: If $Y=g(X)$ then the joint probability $P_{X,Y}$ is highly unlikely to be absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure of $\Bbb R^2$, thus negating the premise for existence of $f_{X,Y}$.

Comment: If $Y=X^2$ then $P((X,Y)\in\{(x,x^2)\mid x\in\mathbb R\})=1$ while at the same time $\lambda(\{(x,x^2)\mid x\in\mathbb R\})=0$. So there cannot be a PDF wrt Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, no. Try it with an even simpler case where $X$ has a standard normal distribution and $Y = X$; then a joint density function $f$, were it to exist, would be supported on the diagonal set $\{(x, x) : x \in \mathbb R\}$, which has measure $0$ on the coordinate plane. This would imply that $\iint_{\mathbb R^2} f \, \textrm{d}A = 0$, meaning it wouldn't do what a joint density needs to do.

Comment: I'm making this a community wiki answer because it contributes little beyond what Gae S and drhab said in the comments.